# image container is increased height in chrome browser after hosting a site

Tags: html, google-chrome, materialize

in chrome browser, my web page images are shows with blurred view, images are not shown in actual size. it shows like zoom view. and my web page is used materialize css.

this code is work in local site but after hosting it will show image blurred with increased height (in chrome browser).

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>create review</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <base href="http://example.com/demo/">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="images/favicon.ico"> 
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">       
</head>

<body> 

<main class="homepage">
<!-- navigation bar -->
<header>
    <nav class="navbarCustom">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
          <a href="home" class="brand-logo"><img class="responsive-img brand_icon" src="images/logo.png"></a> 
          <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"> 
<i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
          <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down navMenuList desktopView">
            <li class=""><a href="menu1">Menu1</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="menu2">Menu2</a></li>                 
          </ul>  
        </div>

        <ul class="side-nav navMenuList" id="mobile-demo">
            <li><a href="menu1">menu1</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="menu2">Menu2</a></li>             
        </ul>  
    </nav>  
</header>   
</main>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"> </script>
</html>
```

see page view compare here (Chrome view and Firefox view). [image]

Comment: web server is creating this problem? but it showing only in chrome browser.

Comment: firefox is work fine check image.